# Terelik DatePickerFor throwing exception on click of month name (eg March 2012) in the calendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I am using Terelik Date Picker in my project and when i click on the date picker i have the calendar popped up and i want to quickly change years/months so i clicked on March 2012 (current Month label) My code is throwing exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i fixed it.. it was because i have a style `fontsize: smaller` set for the `calendar` and in jquery 1.5.1.min it is trying to parse `smaller` as `int` and throwing an exception and hence the issue. i changed the `font-size` to numeric value and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the relevant code and also the exception being thrown? I'd presume that this is Telerik MVC controls.

Comment: In addition to the Jquery Plugin this is the code which i use


@(Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name(test).HtmlAttributes(new { id = test + "_date" }).Max(DateTime.Today).Value(DateTime.Today).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size: 12px;" }))